# Can an undefined value be said to be not an element of a defined set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

With our normal axioms of set theory is it proper to say that an undefined value is not an element of a set containing all defined values?

As an example we could be asking "Is the final digit in the decimal expansion $0.101010...$ a member of the set $\{0,1\}$?" Here the final digit is not defined but saying "the final digit is neither $0$ nor $1$" is in one way having some defined final digit to compare with $0$ and $1$.

What this boils down to is does it make sense to compare an undefined value to many defined values?

Comment: Is the present king of France bald?

Comment: @BrianO Not sure, but there is no non-bald king of france

Comment: Nor is there a bald one, presently. Point is, the phrase seems to denote something, but doesn't. Similarly for the phrase "an undefined value": there is no such value, no such thing, no such "it", nothing can be said, talk of comparing "it" to anything is meaningless. And so on :)

Comment: Great this is just what I suspected the logic behind undefinables would be.  Just to confirm, this means that we also cannot say that "1/0 is not an element of the set of reals"? I'm not sure if this would be a different type of undefined.

Comment: That's right, you can't say "1/0 \in \Bbb R" or $\notin$, for that matter. An alternate theory is Russell's "theory of definite descriptions", according to which such statements are just false (both of them). A "definite descirption" is a definition of a term of the form "the such and such". According to Russell, "the present king of France is bald" really means "there is one and one present king of France, and he is bald" -- which is simply false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as an 'undefined value', because if a value is undefined, then it isn't a value. When we say something is undefined, what we really mean is either that a written expression has no meaning, or that there are no objects with a certain property.

Here, 'the last digit of $0.101010\dots{}$' is undefined, in the sense that $0.101010\dots$ has no last digit. So when you ask if something is true of the last digit of $0.101010\dots{}$, you're asking if a property holds of an element of the empty set... which is not a very fruitful business.

Comment: Admirably put. The language seemingly allowing us to talk about things that do not exist causes confusion. (I wish the last sentence wasn't exactly the way it is - it's important to understand that every element of the empty set _is_ an off perfect number... Not that that contradicts what you said, but.)

Comment: Thank you that is enlightening. I hadn't thought of the set of last digits of 0.101010... to be the empty set